# Correlation_id in rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I was looking at a piece of code that uses callback_queue with correlation_id on default exchange. But when I tried to change it to a user defined exchange, I am not getting any reply back on that queue. To test it I tried this very simple example from https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html and I found if I use a exchange other than default I don't get any reply. Please let me know if there's anything else I should do. Thanks

```
   ../rabbitmq $ ./rpc_client.py 1
    (' [x] Requesting fib%s', '1')
     [.] Got 1

    ../rabbitmq $ ./rpc_client.py 19
    (' [x] Requesting fib%s', '19')


    .../rabbitmq $ ./rpc_server.py
 [x] Awaiting RPC requests
 [.] fib(1)
 [.] fib(19)
```

If I change my exchange='' to exchange='test'(test is the exchange I created) in the scripts , I noticed the consumer just sits..If I use default I get a reply back..

```
../rabbitmq $ ./rpc_server.py   
 [x] Awaiting RPC requests

../rabbitmq $ ./rpc_client.py 1 
(' [x] Requesting fib%s', '1')
```

I also looked at [correlationId and temporary queues in RPC model - AMQP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508553/correlationid-and-temporary-queues-in-rpc-model-amqp)

and https://github.com/eandersson/python-rabbitmq-examples/blob/master/Flask-examples/pika_async_rpc_example.py

Comment: You most likely need to add a binding in your request queue to the new exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add bindings to your queues if you are using a custom exchange. This applies to both the `rpc_queue` and the reply queue (e.g. amq.gen-xxx).

In the `rpc_client.py` example from [RabbitMQ](http://rabbitmq.com) add `queue_bind` after `result.method.queue`.

```
self.channel.queue_bind(self.callback_queue, 'test', self.callback_queue)
```

In the `rpc_server.py` example add `queue_bind` after `queue_declare`.

```
channel.queue_bind('rpc_queue', 'test', 'rpc_queue')
```

The reason you need to add a binding is because you are not using the default exchange. The default exchange automatically binds to all queues, so you do not need to add the above bindings for it to work. You can read more about the default exchange [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html#exchange-default).